Dimension of the Hilbert Scheme of conics
I am trying to compute the dimension of the Hilbert Scheme of conics in $\mathbb{P}^4$ $Hilb_{2T+1}(\mathbb{P}^4)$. I started with conics lying on a plane, so, taking the ideal $I=(Q,H_1,H_2)$ for two hyperplanes $H_1,H_2$ independent of $Q$. I know that we can map $I_2$ to the subspace $\mathbb{P}(I_2)$, thus embedding our scheme into $\mathbb{G}(9,14)$. I tried to use an incidence variety so that I was able to count dimensions via fibers, but I am stuck.

A conic in $\mathbb{P}^4$ is determined by its linear span, which is a point of $\mathrm{Gr}(3,5)$, and a conic in this linear span. Thus, the Hilber scheme of conics admits a fibration
$$
\operatorname{Hilb}_{2T+1}(\mathbb{P}^4) \to \mathrm{Gr}(3,5)
$$
with fiber $\mathbb{P}^5$. In particular,
$$
\dim(\operatorname{Hilb}_{2T+1}(\mathbb{P}^4)) =
\dim(\mathrm{Gr}(3,5)) + \dim(\mathbb{P}^5) = 6 + 5 = 11.
$$

I am not sure I understand the first sentence. I see how assuming that, the fibration sends every conic to the corresponding point in $Gr(3,5)$, and the family of conics that are mapped to a certain point in $Gr(3,5)$ has dimension $5$, but how did you determine that map?

Also, I proved that the scheme of plane conics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ has dimension $8$. Could I use a change of coordinates sending every conic in $\mathbb{P}^4$ to a plane conic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and use that it is a fibration with fiber $\mathbb{P}^3$?

To define the map you can consider any family $C \to \mathbb{P}^5 \times B$ of conics in $\mathbb{P}^5$ and consider the natural morphism $$H^0(\mathbb{P}^5, \mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^5}(1)) \otimes \mathcal{O}B \to p{2*}p_1^*\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^5}(1)$$ on $B$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the projections of $B$. This is a surjection from a rank 5 trivial bundle to a rank 3 vector bundle, hence defines a morphism to $\mathrm{Gr}(3,5)$.

Great, thank you!
